# Representations on $V\otimes W$ that factor as the tensor product of representations on $V$ and $W$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, tensor-products

$G$ is a group and $V$, $W$ are finite dimensional complex vector spaces. I have a representation $\pi: G \to GL(V\otimes W)$ and I want to know if it factors via two representations $\pi_1: G \to V$ and $\pi_2: G \to W$ so that $\pi = \pi_1 \otimes \pi_2$.

It's clear that not all representations $\pi$ factor this way. For example, let $G = C_2 = \{e, \tau\}$ and let $V,W$ have dimension 2 with basis $v_1,v_2$ and $w_1, w_2$ respectively. Define the representation via the action on the basis: $\pi(\tau) v_1\otimes w_1 = v_2\otimes w_1$, $\;\pi(\tau) v_2\otimes w_1 = v_1\otimes w_1$, $\;\pi(\tau) v_1\otimes w_2 = v_1\otimes w_2$, $\;\pi(\tau) v_2\otimes w_2 = v_2\otimes w_2$. If this representation were to factor, $\pi_2(\tau)$ would have to act on $W$ trivially, but then $\pi_1(\tau) v_1 = v_2$ and also $\pi_1(\tau) v_1 = v_1$, a contradiction.

A (maybe simpler?) related question is: From a linear algebra perspective, what is the characteristic property of the linear operators $A \in L(V\otimes W)$ that factor the following way? $A v\otimes w = (B v)\otimes (C w)$ where $B \in L(V)$ and $C\in L(W)$.

Finally, I want to know if there is a nice theory of factoring representations into tensor products. Just like we can check if a rep on $U = V\oplus W$ factors as a direct sum of representations on $V$ and $W$ by simply checking if $V$ and $W$ are invariant subspaces of the rep, is there an analogous property for the tensor product?

Comment: If you are fine with factoring as a tensor product *up to isomorphism*, there is a convenient answer in a lot of settings using character theory. Your linear algebra question also has a well-known answer (albeit an ugly one), but I'm uncertain if each $\pi(g)$ decomposing as a tensor product of linear maps individually implies that the entire representation $\pi$ as a whole decomposes as a tensor product of representations.

Comment: @Thorgott It seems to me that it doesn't: if we make $S_n$ act on some $V^{\otimes n}$ by permuting the tensor factors, then taking for instance the Klein subgroup of $S_4$ (of double transpositions), each element preserves a tensor product of the form $V^{\otimes 2}\otimes V^{\otimes 2}$, but with different factors for each one, and there should be no global factorization.

Comment: @CaptainLama This is a good example, but I think it exposes an ambiguity in what I meant. The question about whether a map decomposes as a tensor product is tested relative to a fixed decomposition $V=V_1\otimes V_2$ of the space as a tensor product. In your example, the different maps factor over different decompositions of the total space. My question should really be that if all $\pi(g)$ factorize *over a fixed decomposition*, then does $\pi$ factorize?

Comment: Ah, well, I don't see how it would not. Maybe an important point is that once the decomposition of $V$ is fixed, if some endomorphism $u$ decomposes as $u_1\otimes u_2$, then $u_1$ and $u_2$ are uniquely determined (because we are working over a field, so everything is faithfully flat or whatever). So if $\pi(g)=\pi_1(g)\otimes \pi_2(g)$ for all $g$, then $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ are well-defined functions and are automatically representations.